# Multi-boot boot loaders missing after MacOS update

Tags: bootcamp, efi, multi-boot

My MacBook Air (2017) currently has 3 OSes: MacOS, Windows, and Ubuntu (making it work was a nightmare). Yesterday when I opened up rEFInd, only MacOS and the Ubuntu stub loader (which, fortunately, still works) was there. All my partitions were still there, but...

[image: That was it]

...only the MacOS boot loader showed up in the EFI partition.

I suspect that this happened after the recent MacOS update that I did. Now I only have the option to boot into MacOS or Ubuntu.

Output of `$ diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         236.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS U                       1000.0 MB  disk0s3
   4:                 Apple_Boot                         134.2 MB   disk0s4
   5:                  Apple_HFS Unused                  5.0 GB     disk0s5
   6:                  Apple_HFS rEFInd                  200.0 MB   disk0s6
   7:         Microsoft Reserved                         16.8 MB    disk0s7
   8:           Linux Filesystem                         49.9 GB    disk0s8
   9:       Microsoft Basic Data WinData                 75.1 GB    disk0s9
  10:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                125.1 GB   disk0s10

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +236.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            206.9 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 24.7 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                517.8 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk1s4
```

Output of `$ sudo gpt -r show disk0`:

```
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640       2008
     411648  460937496      2  GPT part - 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  461349144    1953120      3  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  463302264     262144      4  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  463564408    9827280      5  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  473391688     262144
  473653832     390624      6  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  474044456       2008
  474046464      32768      7  GPT part - E3C9E316-0B5C-4DB8-817D-F92DF00215AE
  474079232   14611656
  488690888   97394104      8  GPT part - 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4
  586084992  146765184      9  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  732850176  244252672     10  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  977102848       2179
  977105027         32         Sec GPT table
  977105059          1         Sec GPT header
```

And for those who are confused by my setup, I used the "alternative solution" in [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310451/triple-boot-macos-high-sierra-ubuntu-and-windows-without-refind) question.