# Triple boot macOS High Sierra, Linux Mint, and Windows with rEFInd

Tags: macos, multi-boot

I have a MacBook 2015 running macOS High Sierra 10.13.4,I installed Windows 10 using Boot Camp. After that I created two partitions swap,root   to do installed Linux Mint. Finally I installed rEFInd to manage the three OS's,  but where reboot I can't access Windows. It's show message error "rEFInd - Booting OS Starting bootmgfw.efi Using load option '' BlInitializeLibrary failed 0xc00000bb ", How to fix it?
 [image]

Comment: Are your partitions ordered 1. MacOS, 2. Windows, 3. Linux? Are your partitions all primary?

Comment: Yes, That's right.

Comment: Could you run "diskutil list" from terminal and attach the output?

Comment: Hi There, I fixed it, by disabling SIP, and converting MBR to GTP by "sudo gdisk / dev / disk0" , p,x,n,w,Y. Thank you for reply

Comment: @luctp Please add the above as an answer.

Answer (score 12):

I will formalize @luctp's answer seeing as the user is gone and I have (sort of) confirmed that the instructions work:

So here's how the error looks like, when trying to boot Windows from rEFInd:
[image]

The steps below will make the error 0xc00000bb effectively disappear and, for @luctp, seemed to be enough to fix the triple boot. However, in my case, more work had to be done as I explain at the end of the answer.

To get rid of the 0xc00000bb:

- [Download and install gdisk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/).
- [Disable SIP](https://support.studionetworksolutions.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003839246-How-to-disable-Systems-Integrity-Protection-SIP-in-macOS), otherwise you get error the following error when running gdisk: `Problem opening /dev/disk0 for reading! Error is 1.`
- Create a new Protective MBR for your disk using gdisk, start by running on the terminal: `sudo gdisk /dev/disk0`
- (Optional) Choose "p" to have a look at your current GPT partitions, and potentially create a backup of them. Also [look here](https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html) for better ways of backing up the partition table.
- Choose option "x", then option "n" to request the creation of a fresh Protective MBR, then option "w" to write the requested changes to the disk, confirm with Y and exit the tool with "q".

After the steps above, Windows 10 should indeed start booting (whereas before it would simply get stuck in rEFInd).

In my case, however, the Windows 10 EFI boot splash would show on the screen for a few seconds and then suddenly reboot.

What ended up being the solution for having a working triple-boot in my Mac was following [David's Alternative Second Answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/310720/47927), specifically the "The First Way". Now, I can boot to any of the three OSs. Not only that, but I can boot them from either rEFInd directly or through GRUB (for Ubuntu/Windows) after rEFInd or after pressing the Option key on boot.

Comment: Steps under Linux are simpler - gdisk can be installed from your favorite package manager (pacman in my case), and there is no need to disable SIP.

Comment: I did not have to disable SIP for my setup to work on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, also you can run gdisk from Linux itself: `gdisk /dev/disk/by-id/ata-APPLE_SSD_SM0256G_S2Z5N*****`