# MacOS Startup Disk error: "Running Bless to Place Boot Files Failed" (triple boot, MacPro 4,1 -> 5,1)

Tags: bootcamp, high-sierra, unix

**My question is, how do I add a (properly-booting) Ubuntu volume to High Sierra's "Startup Disk" Menu?**

Running MacOS High Sierra, Windows 10 (Legacy, not EFI), and Ubuntu 18.04 (triple-booting on a 2009 MacPro 4,1 w/ firmware upgrade to 5,1). I installed Ubuntu after Windows using the procedure [in this link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/332451/296972). I have a second EFI partition for Ubuntu (scroll down for output from `diskutil list`). I've placed / renamed the boot files so that all three operating systems boot normally using Apple's Startup Manager (holding ALT during bootup) - see [this link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257166/installing-ubuntu-on-mac-with-macos-and-windows-already-installed) and [this link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310451/triple-boot-macos-high-sierra-ubuntu-and-windows-without-refind/310720) for guidelines:

[image: Apple Boot Manager - Natively triple-booting]

However, I cannot select Ubuntu as a bootup option through the "Startup Disk" tool in High Sierra. Initially, the "Startup Disk" menu had no entry for Ubuntu. Then, I followed [these steps](https://glandium.org/blog/?p=2830) to create a dummy mach_kernel file and place a SystemVersion.plist from in `/System/Library/CoreServices/` my Ubuntu EFI partition. Now, Ubuntu appears in my "Startup Disk" menu, however I cannot select it. "Startup Disk" fails to select Ubuntu, and says, "Running bless to place boot files failed."[image: After creating dummy mach_kernel, Startup Disk shows Ubuntu but still fails to boot]
[image: Selecting "Ubuntu" causes this error]

Currently, I'm working around this by using the following bless command to boot directly into Ubuntu from High Sierra (only works if `csrutil` is disabled in Recovery):

```
sudo bless --device /dev/disk0s5 --setboot --nextonly && sudo reboot
```

It works for now, but I would appreciate any insights on how to add Ubuntu to High Sierra's "Startup Disk." Thanks!

Output of `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            1.5 TB     disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                290.3 GB   disk0s4
   5:                  Apple_HFS Ubuntu                  200.3 MB   disk0s5
   6:                 Linux Swap                         8.0 GB     disk0s6
   7:           Linux Filesystem                         201.5 GB   disk0s7
```

Comment: I can't hope to provide an answer on this, though I have a similar machine... but I often wonder why it wouldn't be simpler to just run all this in VMs. A Mac Pro has sufficient raw power, even allowing for its age, that a VM would just seem... easier.

Comment: @Tetsujin, Thanks! I set up VirtualBox, but encountered some difficulties setting up a virtual hard drive based on my existing native installation. I'm very happy with the speed of a native installation (now that it boots) compared to a VM - just a question of ease of transit between the different operating systems.