# Running bless to place boot files failed

Tags: terminal, bootcamp, startup, ssd

I have just cloned the internal hard drive on a Macbook Pro 2013 to an SSD drive, but I keep getting "Running bless to place boot files failed” message if I try to boot from it.

I tried entering this command in the terminal `diskutil apfs updatePreboot /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/`
but it still doesn't work. Anybody got any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate, please check https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332742/macos-startup-disk-error-running-bless-to-place-boot-files-failed-triple-boo

Comment: As I do not consider this an answer, I'll offer it as a comment: Since cloning itself appears to have not quite succeeded and assuming that you have a valid TimeMachine backup, I'd be inclined to Cmd-R to boot into recovery mode, run Disk Utility and repair the volume. If that doesn't completely solve the problem, reboot Cmd-R and restore the volume from TimeMachine backup.

Comment: hi Trane, will try restoring it from time machine during boot up at disk utility, thank for the suggestion