# Triple boot: “Missing operating system” on Windows 10 partition after Windows update

Tags: bootcamp, windows, partition, dual-boot, efi

I have a triple booted MacBook Pro (using rEFInd as boot manager). Recently I selected "Update and shut down" when finishing up in Windows 10. Since then, rEFInd still offers Windows to boot from, but the system responds with "Missing operating system". I've tried repairing using a Windows recovery USB according to the suggestion [here](https://superuser.com/questions/986134/tried-triple-boot-on-mbp-broke-windows), but 0 Windows installations are found.

I've also tried fixing the MBR using the methods discussed [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/325500/triple-boot-missing-operating-system-on-windows-7-partition-after-ubuntu-inst), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1216055/hybrid-mbr-triple-boot-on-a-macbook), and [here](http://nerdr.com/bootcamp-partition-lost-repairing-mac-partitions/), but to no avail.

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         490.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Linux Swap                         10.0 GB    disk0s3
   4:           Linux Filesystem                         250.0 GB   disk0s4
   5:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         250.0 GB   disk0s5

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +490.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh SSD           173.2 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 23.0 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                507.2 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +ERROR      disk2
                                 Physical Store disk0s5
```

Partition 5 on disk0 used to be the Bootcamp install of Windows 10. Now it is on disk2.

```
    sudo gpt -r -vv show disk0
gpt show: disk0: mediasize=1000204886016; sectorsize=512; blocks=1953525168
gpt show: disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
gpt show: disk0: Pri GPT at sector 1
gpt show: disk0: Sec GPT at sector 1953525167
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         MBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640   957031248      2  GPT part - 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   957440888    19531248      3  GPT part - 0657FD6D-A4AB-43C4-84E5-0933C84B4F4F
   976972136   488276496      4  GPT part - 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4
  1465248632   488276496      5  GPT part - 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  1953525128           7         
  1953525135          32         Sec GPT table
  1953525167           1         Sec GPT header
```

sudo fdisk /dev/disk0

```
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 121601/255/63 [1953525168 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE    0   0   2 - 1023 254  63 [         1 - 1465248631] <Unknown ID>
*2: AF 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [1465248632 -  488276496] HFS+        
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

Any help is very much appreciated. I have files on the partition I'd really prefer not to lose.

`sudo dd if=/dev/disk0s5 count=1 | hexdump -Cv`

``` 1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes transferred in 0.000428 secs (1195704 bytes/sec)
00000000  98 ce 13 79 db ae e7 88  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |...y............|
00000010  63 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 80 00 00 00 00  |c...............|
00000020  4e 58 53 42 00 10 00 00  42 50 a3 03 00 00 00 00  |NXSB....BP......|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  64 b6 65 e7 3d 15 45 f6  |........d.e.=.E.|
00000050  83 17 cd a9 fa 33 c0 8e  d0 bc 00 7c fb 68 c0 07  |.....3.....|.h..|
00000060  1f 1e 68 66 00 cb 88 16  0e 00 66 81 3e 03 00 4e  |..hf......f.>..N|
00000070  54 46 53 75 15 b4 41 bb  aa 55 cd 13 72 0c 81 fb  |TFSu..A..U..r...|
00000080  55 aa 75 06 f7 c1 01 00  75 03 e9 dd 00 1e 83 ec  |U.u.....u.......|
00000090  18 68 1a 00 b4 48 8a 16  0e 00 8b f4 16 1f cd 13  |.h...H..........|
000000a0  9f 83 c4 18 9e 58 1f 72  e1 3b 06 0b 00 75 db a3  |.....X.r.;...u..|
000000b0  0f 00 c1 2e 0f 00 04 1e  5a 33 db b9 00 20 2b c8  |........Z3... +.|
000000c0  66 ff 06 11 00 03 16 0f  00 8e c2 ff 06 16 00 e8  |f...............|
000000d0  4b 00 2b c8 77 ef b8 00  bb cd 1a 66 23 c0 75 2d  |K.+.w......f#.u-|
000000e0  66 81 fb 54 43 50 41 75  24 81 f9 02 01 72 1e 16  |f..TCPAu$....r..|
000000f0  68 07 bb 16 68 52 11 16  68 09 00 66 53 66 53 66  |h...hR..h..fSfSf|
00000100  55 16 16 16 68 b8 01 66  61 0e 07 cd 1a 33 c0 bf  |U...h..fa....3..|
00000110  0a 13 b9 f6 0c fc f3 aa  e9 fe 01 90 90 66 60 1e  |.............f``.|
00000120  06 66 a1 11 00 66 03 06  1c 00 1e 66 68 00 00 00  |.f...f.....fh...|
00000130  00 66 50 06 53 68 01 00  68 10 00 b4 42 8a 16 0e  |.fP.Sh..h...B...|
00000140  00 16 1f 8b f4 cd 13 66  59 5b 5a 66 59 66 59 1f  |.......fY[ZfYfY.|
00000150  0f 82 16 00 66 ff 06 11  00 03 16 0f 00 8e c2 ff  |....f...........|
00000160  0e 16 00 75 bc 07 1f 66  61 c3 a1 f6 01 e8 09 00  |...u...fa.......|
00000170  a1 fa 01 e8 03 00 f4 eb  fd 8b f0 ac 3c 00 74 09  |............<.t.|
00000180  b4 0e bb 07 00 cd 10 eb  f2 c3 0d 0a 41 20 64 69  |............A di|
00000190  73 6b 20 72 65 61 64 20  65 72 72 6f 72 20 6f 63  |sk read error oc|
000001a0  63 75 72 72 65 64 00 0d  0a 42 4f 4f 54 4d 47 52  |curred...BOOTMGR|
000001b0  20 69 73 20 63 6f 6d 70  72 65 73 73 65 64 00 0d  | is compressed..|
000001c0  0a 50 72 65 73 73 20 43  74 72 6c 2b 41 6c 74 2b  |.Press Ctrl+Alt+|
000001d0  44 65 6c 20 74 6f 20 72  65 73 74 61 72 74 0d 0a  |Del to restart..|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 8a 01  a7 01 bf 01 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200 ```

Comment: Can you find your files via macOS? Does the Windows partition mount properly? If so, you can then go to macOS and copy whichever files you want from Finder or Terminal.

Comment: What is the year of your Mac? What version of macOS? Can you boot to linux? Which linux is installed?

Comment: It doesn't mount properly. Disk Utility calls it an invalid disk. It's a late 2011 model. I used the process from this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mLYTKnEifDU) to set it up originally. It worked perfectly for 6 months or so. Booting to linux still works. I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed.

Comment: If you can boot to macOS and boot to Linux, then you probably overwrote your Windows NTFS filesystem before you posted your question.

Comment: Alright, that's disappointing, but I do appreciate your help. Any idea how this could happen? I was using Windows normally last week, but I've read that sometimes an OS update can mess up the boot record, so I thought that the forced update caused the boot failure. Obviously when I reinstall Windows I'd like to avoid this happening again.

Answer (score 1):

### How to Fix the Partition Tables

If you have a 2011 model Mac, then you should be using Hybrid partitioning. From linux, you could enter the following commands to restore hybrid partitioning.

```
sudo gdisk /dev/sda
t
5
0700
r
h
5
y
07
y
n
w
y
```

If you computer does not boot, then you may need to rebuild the Windows boot files and data. This would require creating a bootable Windows 10 flash drive.

### How to Rebuild the Boot Files and Data

After EFI booting from the Windows 10 flash drive, navigate to where you can open a Command Prompt window or just press the <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> key combination. Enter the command given below to determine the drive letter where windows is installed.

```
echo list volume | diskpart
```

Here, I will assume the drive letter is `C:`. If you have a different drive letter then make the appropriate substitutions. To recreate the boot files and data, enter the commands given below.

```
bootsect /nt60 c: /mbr
attrib -h -s -r c:\boot\bcd
del c:\boot\bcd
bcdboot c:\windows /s c: /f bios
```

If you do not have a `c:\boot\bcd` file, then you will get error messages regarding this file. You can ignore these messages.

> Note: Since you are EFI booted from the flash drive and Windows 10 is installed on the internal drive to BIOS boot, the command `bootrec /rebuildbcd` can **not** be used.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. It still isn't booting into Windows. I have a bootable Windows 10 flash drive. Previously when I booted using the USB and selected "repair your computer" I tried the given Troubleshoot options, and also tried the "bootrec /fixmbr" steps from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/986134/tried-triple-boot-on-mbp-broke-windows). I'll try it again since I hadn't previously done the first 3 steps from your response.

Comment: The Repair Your PC steps again could not find any Windows installations, but after doing the "bootrec /fixmbr" steps, rEFInd now gives another bootable option "Boot from (Legacy) Windows installation", but booting from this just gives a black screen.

Comment: thanks again. The boot files couldn't be copied. Here is a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/7rcaN0D) of the command prompt window.

Comment: According to your screenshot, you do not have any formatted windows partitions on the internal drive. Can you post the output from the macOS command `sudo dd if=/dev/disk0s5 count=1 | hexdump -Cv`?

Comment: Sure, added to the main section. This section has an extra tick mark for markdown formatting: |.............f``.|