# Replace windows installation on Macbook pro with Ubuntu

Tags: macos, unix, dual-boot

I have a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2010) running OS X El Capitan with dual boot Windows.

I would like to replace windows with Ubuntu 18.04.

The command `disktil list` shows:

```
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *256.1 GB   disk0
1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
2:                  Apple_HFS SSJony                  127.0 GB   disk0s2
3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                128.2 GB   disk0s4
```

I would like to increase the size of the Mac by half, to around 192 GB and the rest for Ubuntu. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

First step would be to delete the Windows partition using a program like Disk Utility of GParted (which is often included in the Ubuntu live disk). This will give you some unallocated space that you may be able to expand the MacOS partition to.

After you've increased the size to what you want, you can run the installation of Ubuntu and create a new partition out of the remaining unallocated space. This can usually be done during the installation process.