# Making Uninitialized APFS Volume Bootable

Tags: macos, high-sierra, bootcamp, unix, bootable-disk

Recently I installed Ubuntu on my MacBook Pro (Mid 2012) on a second volume. I wanted to change to the Ubuntu Volume through Startup Manager and used this tutorial to do so: [Installing Ubuntu on Mac with macOS and Windows already installed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257166/installing-ubuntu-on-mac-with-macos-and-windows-already-installed)

All in all I messed around with EFI but it worked. Yesterday I uninstalled Ubuntu and after doing that I could not access my macOS Bootable Volume (with High Sierra)! In Disk Util the Type was set to (FFFF.FFFF,...) which I changed to the correct code for APFS, but it still wouldn’t boot or show in Startup manager.

Anyway I used the Ubuntu partition to reinstall OSX High Sierra which of course did not help accessing my original Volume.

I was able to access my data with third Party data recovery software but I need to make this Volume bootable again. In Diskutil it says that the Volume is Uninitialized (Volume is APFS Format.) Is there anything I can do? If you need more info please ask!

Thats my current diskutil list output:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *256.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         190.8 GB   disk0s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS Untitled                3.9 GB     disk0s3
   4:           Linux Filesystem                         500.2 MB   disk0s4
   5:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         41.4 GB    disk0s5

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +ERROR      disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +41.4 GB    disk2
                                 Physical Store disk0s5
   1:                APFS Volume disk0s5                 15.2 GB    disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 21.2 MB    disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                516.1 MB   disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk2s4
```

Comment: What are you trying to refer to as "AFTPS"? Do you mean APFS?

Comment: @duskwuff yes sorry I misspelled that!