# UBUNTU on MacOS, windows already installed

Tags: macos, windows, unix, dual-boot

I am installing UBUNTU on my MACOS Mojave while windows 10 is already installed through bootcamp. I've tried the instructions in [Installing Ubuntu on Mac with macOS and Windows already installed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257166/installing-ubuntu-on-mac-with-macos-and-windows-already-installed/257275#257275) but somehow got stuck.

Can anybody please help me, I tried many times but failed. I tried through dual boot but te wifi, keyboard and trackpad not working. also there was no boot manage option for the UBUNTU once the USB drive was removed.

[image: my MACMODEL]
[image: diskutil list]
[image: please see this, I want to start from disk partition. here is the result of the ''commands '' which you said in one of your ports. sir David ANderson]

Comment: What have you tried so far, which instructions are you following, where exactly does it fail (and how)?

Comment: I did this a long time ago with windows 7. At the time windows could not be the last partition on my Apple computer. That way the windows boot loader could give me an option to boot into Linux. It was not worth the effort to setup or maintain. I am not sure if the method I used even works anymore. If you need Linux why not just set up a box at home and remote into as you need it?

Comment: I actually need all of these, few tools i am using they work on windows and few work on ubuntu. There is a user who has done it, David Anderson, But I am . not able to contact him or ask hime. can you please help me so that I can contact him? I an new user here. thank u so much

Comment: Dear Nohilside, I have tried using dual boot.couple of times I finished, but when it starts it  doesnt connect with wifi and its keyboard and mouse doesnt work. I have to connect usb mouse and keyboard while if I remove the usb stick its boot manager doesnt give ubuntu log in option, it gives GNU GRUB error.

Comment: We can't see your screen, so you will need to help us in understanding what's going on. I assume you are following some instructions from a webpage, please add a link (or describe in detail the steps you've already taken). Also helpful is an output of `diskutil list` and similar.

Comment: In addition there are a tons of questions about triple boot, and Linux/Windows already on AD. Even if they may not match your particular problem they may help in giving you some ideas on the details required.

Comment: hy David, I was talknig about you. Am sorry, am new here. i saw your post i tried to follow your instructions but i was not able to post any comment. I am trying add some screenshots but i dont have any option.. Can you please help me a bit.

Comment: Khan, if you post a comment and include `@David Anderson`, then I will be notified. It  would help if you could edit your question and add the model/year of your Mac and the output from the command `diskutil list`. Hopefully, you can be directed to an existing answer. Otherwise, maybe the hold could be lifted. Can you add a link to my answer that your are referring to?

Comment: @David Anderson here is the link which i was following. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257166/installing-ubuntu-on-mac-with-macos-and-windows-already-installed/257275#257275 . while I am going to add the screen shot for the command DISKUTILLIST

Comment: If you are using Mojave, then the instructions posted in my answer are not going to work. First, the `gpt` and `fdisk` commands will not work unless System Integrity Protection (SIP) is disabled. Second, your macOS partition is APFS so the `diskutil resizevolume` command will not work. Did you post the model/year of your Mac?

Comment: @DavidAnderson yes I am using mojave, what should I do? and what if i am successfly able to install using mojave but later I update my macOS?

Comment: yes I have uploaded in the picture as well, its "MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)"

Comment: I can update my instructions for when the operating system is Mojave. However, you stated the wifi, keyboard and trackpad do not work. After installing Ubunutu, if these still do not work there is very little I can recommend to fix these problems.

Comment: ok, that would be massive favor if you do so, for wifi and other functions I will use ethernet and external inputs.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thanks for jumping in. Please flag/vote to close if you update the existing answer.

Comment: My internet went down so I have not be able to post comments until now. Unfortunately, it is now noon here in Minneapolis, MN (USA) and I have other duties to preform. I will try to post an updated answer this evening.

Comment: Have you thought about using a virtual machine software?  Free version of Parallels for individual use:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/parallels-desktop-lite/id1085114709?mt=12
Full version
http://www.parallels.com/en/products/desktop/

VMware Fusion
http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/

VirtualBox
http://www.virtualbox.org/

Comment: @DavidAnderson ok, I will wait. do it when you are free. thank you so much for all this.

Comment: @historystamp I am more interested in triple boot. thanks though.

Comment: @DavidAnderson hy David, hope you are doing good. if you have time, Please help me. I shall be very much grateful to you for this.

Comment: @DavidAnderson dear Sir, I hope you are enjoying your time. Please when you have time, help me out. I shall be very grateful to you. thanks in advance.

Comment: useless place, fake admins and waste of time.